# Samsung Galaxy J5 connected to WiFi but network not available

Tags: wi-fi, connection-issues, internet, samsung-galaxy-j5

I bought this brand new Samsung Galaxy J5 yesterday, but I'm stuck with an internet connection problem.

The thing is that the WiFi connection worked properly on the store and at some other places, but in my home, it connects to the WiFi but I don't seem to have any network (I open the browser but can't access any URL). All others devices that I have in my house work very well (other Android devices).

I'm assuming then that :

1. The J5 is working properly (as I can connect it at other places);
2. The WiFi in my home is working properly (as others devices connect to it *and* can access any URL).

I was digging many hours yesterday on the web to find a solution for this but nothing has worked so far. By the way, all "J's" devices seem to have a lot of these issues.

Is it correct to say that I may be facing some kind of compatibility issue, between J5 and my WiFi? If yes, what could I do to solve it?

Comment: Indeed that might be a compatibility issue. I vaguely remember there was something similar in the past with some devices concerning encryption. Check what your router's WiFi is set to here. It might be WEP (unlikely and insecure), WPA, WPA2 or – and that might be the issue here – WPA/WPA2 (i.e. let the client chose). Some devices had trouble with that choice; so if it's set this way in your case, it might be worth trying to fix it to either WPA or WPA2.

Comment: If you had previously made changes to the settings to the router to only allow selected devices, then you might need to add the new device as well. The same thing applies if you setup a only allowed device firewall on your network.

Answer (score -1):

My dual SIM Samsung J5 has problems after restart to find the Provider Connection, so I can't take the calls.

The solution to fix this: after every reboot, start both SIM cards. After that, you can make calls again. Turn off 1 SIM card if you want to save the battery.

You have to do this after every phone reboot. It's easy but important to know this solution.

Comment: This looks like an attempt to solve an issue about mobile data connection, not WiFi connection.